# Many "unresolved external symbol" after installing SFML on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 2d, sfml

I want to get started in creating some games with graphics. From what I've gathered from the internet it seemed to me that SFML is the best tool to get for beginners. I tried to follow the steps indicated in the tutorial [SFML and Visual Studio](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php) (only the DLL setup) and nothing whatsoever...
I've already spent a lot of hours trying to figure out how to do this thing with no success and I hope that, with you here, I'll be able to solve it. These are the errors I get:[image]

This is my setup:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: From the [SFML download page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/), which version exactly did you download? Also, which platform are you compiling for? x86 (32 bit) or x64 (64 bit). That must match the libraries you downloaded.

Comment: I downloaded Visual C++ 15 (2017), I have Visual Studio 2019 installed and I checked for Visual C++ Redistributable and I have 2015-2019 both for x86 and x64. I also checked the platform and it is for 64 bits

Comment: And which Visual C++ 15 (2017) variant did you download? There are two, and your download must match the platform you're compiling for.

Comment: I downloaded the x64 version, because I thought it has to match my OS variant... but even so, no result

Comment: Windows 64 bit can run both 32bit and 64bit executables. But the version needs to match the platform you're compiling against. Although typically it tells you something about incompatible architectures.

Comment: Can you enable [Verbose linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/verbose-print-progress-messages?view=msvc-160) and/or provide us the full linker commandline used? As well as a textual copy of the output window (which is distinct from the error window and contains more information)

Comment: I downloaded the x32 bit version and tried to repeat the exact same steps I did with x64... Good news: errors disappeared
Bad news: new errors appeared :) only 2 now, but still regarding the linker

Comment: Your screenshot makes it clear. You were compiling for 32-bit (/MACHINE:x86) and the linker is complaining that you're giving it 64-bit libraries ("library machine type x64 conflicts with target machine type x86")

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I solved it :D the main problem was that I had the x64 version and stuck with it for the rest of my "solving quest"... The tutorial from SFML website is clear and correct, it was just my mistake because I was thinking of something else...
**Note for who might run into this problem in the future: the version of SFML from their website (x32/x64) is not your PC system type, it is the "target audience" you are working for, the platform you are compiling/working on**. Thank you, Botje, for helping me and making me search more into the problem :D